# Why do plants produce so much more sugar than they use?

Tags: botany, metabolism, fruit, thermodynamics, carbohydrates

I recently asked the question, "Do plants need O<sub>2</sub> to consume energy they've stored via sugar?" to which [@canadianer responded](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28614/do-plants-need-o2-to-consume-energy-theyve-stored-via-sugar?noredirect=1#comment47173_28614), "Yes, plants require oxygen to generate ATP from sugar. However, they generate far more sugar (and O<sub>2</sub>) than they use." Why do plants produce all that extra sugar, especially given that sugar is thermodynamically expensive?

One reason, I believe, is to produce fruit and so recruit animals to help with reproduction. But are there others?

Comment: Plants store sugar as starch and use it to make cellulose (for their cell wall). It's also important to realize that sugar is only one of the products of photosynthesis. The Calvin cycle produces 3 carbon molecules which can feed into other metabolic pathways such as for amino acid or nucleoside synthesis. Basically it's the source of all carbon in plants.

Comment: I just realized my other comment may have been misleading. Of course they use all of the sugar they produce, just not as energy.

Comment: @canadianer, you write, "They use all of the sugar they produce, just not as energy." Why use such an energy-expensive substance for cell walls? Doesn't the high energy content make it more appealing for animals to eat the plant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do plants need O₂ to consume energy they've stored via sugar?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28614/do-plants-need-o%e2%82%82-to-consume-energy-theyve-stored-via-sugar)

Comment: @kuzzooroo Building anything is energy expensive. Anabolic processes are energy expensive but they are essential for survival. Cellulose cannot be digested by all animals. Herbivores got the ability to metabolize cellulose in animals much later than the development of cellulose cell walls in plants, in evolution. (Actually herbivores rely on bacteria to do that)

Comment: Almost no higher animal has cellulase. Some rely on intestinal bacteria to digest the cellulose. Some animals ingest their feces to get the carbohydrates obtained by broken cellulose as the actual digestion of cellulose is in the colon where glucose can't be absorbed.

Comment: @WYSIWYG There are insect herbivores that produce cellulase themselves. It is rare overall (most rely on symbionts, both bacteria, fungi and protozoa), but spread in many insect orders.